# Why is the utf8 IO layer stripped when spawning a daemon process?

Tags: perl, encoding, utf-8

The following code works as expected:

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;
use open qw/:std IN :encoding(utf-8) OUT :utf8/; 

say  join ' ', (PerlIO::get_layers(\*STDOUT));
my $pid = fork();
die "fork() failed: $!" unless defined $pid;
if ($pid == 0) {
    say  join ' ', (PerlIO::get_layers(\*STDOUT));
}
```

**Output**:

```
unix perlio utf8
unix perlio utf8
```

But if I use a daemon process instead of a regular fork:

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;
use open qw/:std IN :encoding(utf-8) OUT :utf8/; 
use Cwd qw(getcwd);
use Proc::Daemon;

my $work_dir = getcwd;    
my $daemon = Proc::Daemon->new(
    work_dir     => $work_dir,
    child_STDOUT => 'stdout.txt',
    child_STDERR => 'stderr.txt',
    pid_file     => 'pid.txt',
);
my $pid = $daemon->Init();
if ( $pid == 0 ) {
    say  join ' ', (PerlIO::get_layers(\*STDOUT));
}
```

The output to the file `stdout.txt` is:

```
unix perlio
```

so the `utf8` IO layer has been stripped off.

Comment: As stated in [the documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Proc-Daemon/lib/Proc/Daemon.pod), that module closes stdin etc. and reopens them. I don't know for sure, but I bet the `open` pragma is lexically scoped like most others; setting it in one package doesn't change how other packages work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this example:

Foo.pm:

```
package Foo;
use warnings;
use strict;
sub test {
  close STDIN;
  open \*STDIN, "<", "/dev/null";
}
1;
```

test.pl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw/say/;
use open qw/:std IN :encoding(UTF-8) OUT :encoding(UTF-8)/;
use lib qw/./;
use Foo;

$, = ' ';
say "Original STDIN:", PerlIO::get_layers(\*STDIN);
close STDIN;
open \*STDIN, "<", "/dev/null";
say "Reopened STDIN:", PerlIO::get_layers(\*STDIN);
Foo::test();
say "Reopened STDIN in different package:", PerlIO::get_layers(\*STDIN);
```

Results:

```
$ perl test.pl
Original STDIN: unix perlio encoding(utf-8-strict) utf8
Reopened STDIN: unix perlio encoding(utf-8-strict) utf8
Reopened STDIN in different package: unix perlio
```

Looks like `use open` is like other pragmas and only applies to the file it's in it. So when `Proc::Daemon` closes standard input, output, and error, and reopens them, it naturally doesn't see the extra layers.

Comment: `use open` is lexically-scoped. (Except the `:std` part, which causes `binmode` to be called immediately)